# White screen on Android cordova 1.8.2 jquery 1.8 and jquery 1.2. application

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I want to get rid of white screen from my cordova andriod application. I am calling new pages through window.document.location. First it will show white screen for couple of second then actual page comes up.

I believe jquery JS is taking time in loading on each page.

Please help.

Thanks

Rajeev Dave

Comment: $.defaultPageTransition:'none'

Comment: I have used everything above coding also but still no luck. It is coming on almost all mobile andriod, iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
window.open('mypagename.html");
```